# JQuery Animate Z-Index?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, z-index, animate.css

In my page I have different menu items that trigger different corresponding pictures. The `z-index` switches the corresponding picture to the top. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var doorOpen = false;

$("a[href=#andrew]").click(function() {

    if (doorOpen) { // set animation duration for door close, based on actually needed to animate the door closed or not
        var duration = 1500;
    } else {
        var duration = 0;
    }

    $("#rightdoor,#leftdoor").animate(
        {"marginLeft":"0px"},
        {duration:duration,
            complete:function() {
                $('.pic2 .pic3 .pic4 .pic5').css('zIndex', 1);  //puts wrong pics in back
                $('.pic1').css('zIndex', 2);  //brings right pic into view
                $('#rightdoor').animate({  //opens doors again
                 marginLeft: "150px",
                }, 1500);
                $('#leftdoor').animate({
                 marginLeft: "-150px",
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
    );

    doorOpen = true;


});

$("a[href=#bugz]").click(function() {

    if (doorOpen) { // set animation duration for door close, based on actually needed to animate the door closed or not
        var duration = 1500;
    } else {
        var duration = 0;
    }

    $("#rightdoor,#leftdoor").animate(
        {"marginLeft":"0px"},
        {duration:duration,
            complete:function() {
                $('.pic1 .pic3 .pic4 .pic5').css('zIndex', 1);  //puts wrong pics in back
                $('.pic2').css('zIndex', 2);  //brings right pic into view
                $('#rightdoor').animate({  //opens doors again
                 marginLeft: "150px",
                }, 1500);
                $('#leftdoor').animate({
                 marginLeft: "-150px",
                }, 1500);
            }
        }
    );

    doorOpen = true;    
});
});
```

The problem is that the `z-index` works but only once per menu item it seems. If you initially click `#andrew`, it brings pic1 to the top and if you click `#bugz` it brings pic2 to the top. However, if you click `#andrew` again it animates the code before and after the `.css(z-index)` change but does not change the `z-index` to bring pic1 back to the top.

I am new to Javascript/JQuery so please forgive me if I am missing something obvious

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is wrong: `$('.pic2 .pic3 .pic4 .pic5')` looks for descendants of `.pic2`.

You could use commas to separate those classes instead of spaces, but it's simpler to use the [`.siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) method instead:

```
$('.pic1').css('zindex',2).siblings().css('zindex',1);
```

Comment: Small issue- everything works but the very first time an item is clicked after the page loads, the right door opens then flickers back to the middle and opens again. Any clue as to why this may be? It only happens on the very first click of the page

Comment: Can't really say without a more complete picture of your code, including HTML and CSS.